# Configuring apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a unbent server with apache2 on it and in: `/etc/apache2/sites-available` I have the file: `adambalan.conf` which looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/*****/WordPress
ServerName adambalan.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I then did:

```
****@localhost:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ 
sudo a2ensite adambalan.conf #=> Enabling site adambalan.
```

**One** The site is `adambalan.com` not `adambalan.`

So I thought, ok ill just restart apache like it told me too ...

When I do and try and go to adambalan.com I don't get my Wordpress stuff, which is all set up[ and ready to go. All I get is the typical - omg apache works. So I don't think the virtual host worked.

Ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: OMG you could have just said that it doesn't have to do with php and wordpress >..>

Comment: But your question isn't about PHP or Wordpress, is it?

Comment: Log files are amazingly useful beasts...

Comment: If I knew where to look I wouldn't be posting here and apache2 starts perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the main `httpd.conf` has `NameVirtualHost *:80`. If not, please add.

Eventhough you are connecting to http://adambalan.com, your browser may be connecting to http://www.adambalan.com if the DNS resolves www.adambalan.com but not adambalan.com.

To cover your bases, use ServerName and ServerAlias in adambalam.conf.

```
ServerName adambalan.com
ServerAlias www.adambalan.com
```

Give it a try.